# Of all the numbers in each row that are less than 1, choose the highest and second-highest

Tags: java

I'm having a practice to find the 2 largest number in each row in a matrix, but it's must be less than 1.

for example matrix is:

```
1,000   0,283   0,372   0,962   
0,283   1,000   0,915   0,232   
0,372   0,915   1,000   0,253   
0,962   0,232   0,253   1,000
```

so I expected the output should be:

```
0,962   0,372
0,915   0,283
0,915   0,372
0,962   0,253
```

What I have done so far didn't give me the out out in the console section
This is my code:

```
public static double[][] Neighbor(double a[][], int m,int n)
{
    double first,second;
first = second = -100;
    double [][]neighbors = new double[m][2];

for(int i = 0; i<m ;i++)
{
 for(int j = 0; j<n;j++)
     if( a[i][j] > first && a[i][j] < 1)
    {
        second = first;
        first = a[i][j];
        neighbors[i][1] = first;
    }

      else if( a[i][j] > second && a[i][j] < 1)
    {
        second = a[i][j];
        neighbors[i][2] = second;
    }
    }
    }   
return neighbors;
}
```

in main:

```
double[][] neighbors = new double[m][2];
neighbors = Neighbor(Ybar,m,m);
System.out.println(); 
for(int i = 0; i < m; i++)
   {
     for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
     {              
        System.out.printf("%.3f   ", neighbors[i][j] );
     }
     System.out.println();
}
```

Is there any problem with my Neighbor function ?
 I'm new with java :)

Comment: 2 Largest number in each row < 1?

Comment: sorry for my bad english. I really don't know how to describe this situation. I would be appreciate if you help me with the grammar :)

Comment: @MariosNikolaou: Of all the numbers in each row that are less than 1, choose the highest and second-highest.

Comment: @Amadan ok got it.

Comment: It didn't show anything

Comment: Array indices start at 0, not 1. See: `neighbors [i][1]` and `neighbors [i][2]`. You don't reset second and first back to -100 after one row is complete.

Comment: Your matrix contains decimal fractions. In English the dot is used and not the comma, so, for example, 1/2 is written as 0.5

Comment: Also, the first new is pointless, as you are immediately reassigning the variable `neighbors` to the result of the function call: `double[][] neighbors = new double[m][2];
neighbors = Neighbor(Ybar,m,m);`

Comment: thanks for pointing out my error, I added "neighbors[i][1] = second" in the first if-condition and now It worked perfectly, many thanks :)